# Vuforia licensing for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing an app for iOS and Android with Unity. I'm using Vuforia in my application and I have and classic license. As far as I know I can use the license for both platforms. I used metaio before vuforia and for metaio license the bundle identifiers had to be different. So my question is can the bundle identifiers of android and ios builds be different or should they be the same for vuforias license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One license should be enough if this is exactly the same app on Android and iOS.

From Vuforia's support forum:
"Each license key can only be used in a single app. You will need to create a unique license key for each Vuforia app that you develop, though you can use the same license key for the Android and iOS versions of the app."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes the applications are exactly the same. Only the identifiers are different. If vuforia is checking for license, with these identifiers, the applications would seem different. But if thats not the case it should be no problem I guess.

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure, put a post on their support forum. Good luck!